# How to mix a Has One relationship and a Has Many on the same table

Tags: go, go-gorm

Starting from a basic `Has Many` relationship

```
type Owner struct {
    ID         uint      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Owned      []Owned   `gorm:"foreignkey:OwnerId"`
}

typ Owned struct{
    ID         uint      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    OwnerId    uint
}
```

Witch gave the following SQL database

```
Owner
ID 
1
2

Owned 
ID | OwnerId
1  |       1
2  |       1
3  |       1
4  |       2
5  |       2
```

I would like to have a column `FavoriteOwnedId` in the owner table to reference my favorite owned row. Which should look like that:

```
Owner
ID | FavoriteOwnedId
1  |               2
2  |               5

Owned 
ID | OwnerId
1  |       1
2  |       1
3  |       1
4  |       2
5  |       2
```

I imagine something like the following would allow me to get it

```golang
owner := &Owner
db.Where("id = ?", someId).
   Preload("FavoriteOwned").
   Preload("Owned").
   First(&owner)
```

But I cannot find a way to write the necessary gorm tag to make it work. I manage to write the `Has One` or the `Has Many` but not writing them simultaneously.

Any idea ?